# MASM include guards not working

Tags: assembly, include, masm

I'm writing a multi-module app with MASM 6.14 for DOS. There are four asm files so far and all of them include "main.inc" at the very beginning. Also, I've enabled the /Zf switch and forced all symbols to be public. To invoke ML.EXE, instead of compiling every source file individually I'm using a response file so it can handle all files at once.

in include main.inc:

```
ifndef __MAIN_INC__
       __MAIN_INC__ = 1

    ; some segment definitions here

else
    echo 'This file is being included more than once!'
endif
```

However it's not working. The assembler won't show any warnings and only the linker will complain about it (Error L2025: symbol defined more than once).

It seems as if symbols were only declared within the current .asm file the assembler is working with. Is maybe this the expected behavior? If so, how can I prevent include files to be included more than once?

Comment: Can you find any examples of using include guards in MASM? It might be so that the syntax you use is not what is commonly used.

Comment: In MASM itself. There is a masm32,lib at \masm32\m32lib with all the source files.

Comment: What if you use `IFNDEF __MAIN_INC__`
`__MAIN_INC__ equ <1>` [snip] `ELSE` [snip] `ENDIF` ?

Comment: I also tried that. It didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

Conventionally, the conditional is tested and declared if necessary in the INC file

```
#ifndef __MAIN_INC__
#define __MAIN_INC__

 .... Whatever needs to be here

 #endif
```

This does not mean it can't be tested outside, but this is the most common way to avoid multiple inclusions.

Comment: The conditional is declared in the INC file, I edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: Just with `#define __MAIN_INC__` will set it to non zero.